# Another phrase or term for suicide

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm writing a paper about the threats of cyberbullying and require some help.

My question is I want to explain that cyberbullying can not only damage one's emotion and feeling but can also results in suicide in some severe cases.

However, I find the term suicide some what extreme and controversial.

I will be having a public speech about my paper and don't want to upset any audiences using extreme term.

Should a phrase 'taking one's life' be replaced for the term suicide?

English isn't my native language, so I'm going to need some help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure that "taking one's life" is any less extreme/controversial. The word "suicide" seems fairly antiseptic -- in the details is where the controversy lies, it seems to me.

Comment: The term "suicide" doesn't beat around the bush like other terms do.  If you're discussing something such as cyberbullying (or bullying of any sort) you don't want to tip-toe around the issues.  I don't think the word will "upset" anyone, but its added strength may help drive home the importance of your topic, whereas another term will be less convincing.

Comment: I agree on your points. But I was aware since some people are from different cultural backgrounds and religious point of view, so some avoid using the term suicide. But I can clearly see the point you made, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: If you want to emphasize how serious cyberbullying can be, don't avoid an unpleasant term.  Suicide is the word to use.  I'm not sure why you are  worried about "different cultural backgrounds and religious points of view" when you are using a word to describe a danger.  You are not advocating suicide, you are saying it happens.

Answer (score 1):

"taking one's life" is commonly used.

"take your (own) life"
"to ​kill yourself"

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-your-own-life

Answer (score 0):

You can also "taking one's own life voluntarily and intentionally"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Ending one's life".